# Elgamal Encryption & decryption

Tags: encryption, elgamal

if a game is sending encrypted data by Elgamal and u have (p g y ) while game should send a=g^k mod p and b=(msg)*y^k mod p,so u gonna recieve (a,b) and the recieved msg is in hex form
such w/e like ......................
This is just Example ( not true Hex)

```
 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b 91 12 d4 a5 2a 1c e5 9a 4b
```

...
how i can know where is a and where is b? is there anyway to know them? so i can decrypt them.
note:I have (p g y) which game uses

Comment: That is good question, but no one here can know the answer. You have to ask the game designer what the format of the data will be.